# How to save image in django database?

Tags: python, django

I have a newclaim form which allows user to upload a picture

The current problem I faced is whenever I try to upload a new picture, it is not stored on my database (which is my models.py)

How do I solve this?

**This is my views.py**

```
    def NewClaim(request):
  context = initialize_context(request)
  user = context['user']
  form = ClaimForm()
  lastimage= Image.objects.last()
  imagefile= lastimage.imagefile

  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ClaimForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect ('ViewClaim')

  return render(request, "User/NewClaim.html", {'user':user, 'form':form, 'date': x})


**This is my newclaim.html**

    <form action="/newclaim/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <div>
                    <input id="receipt" type="file" name="receipt_field" style="display: none; visibility: none;">
          </div>
    </form>
```

**This is my saveclaimform models**

```
class SaveClaimForm(models.Model):
    receipt = models.FileField(upload_to='receipts/%Y/%m/%D', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['jpg','png'])])
```

Comment: It doesnt get stored into your DB, it gets stored to the path you defined in your models.py inside your media folder defined in your settings.py

Comment: ```upload_to='receipts/%Y/%m/%D'``` - Do you know why you are using this ?

Comment: Let me make some amendments to the code.

Comment: Apparently, it is to store in a folder called receipts?

Comment: I have updated the views.py

Comment: You can always base64 encode the image and store it in a TextField. Disclaimer: the fact that you CAN do it doesn't mean that you SHOULD do it, it's not a good idea for production, but it's simple enough and could save time in personal projects.

Answer (score 1):

```
  form = ClaimForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  if form.is_valid():
     now take file input here
     and process form as usual
```

Comment: What you mean by file input?

Comment: request.POST.get('receipt_field')

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this [article](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-insert-images-into-a-database-table-with-Python-in-Django.php). Make sure you've modified the settings.py file and the urls.py file to include the info about where you're going to be storing the images.

Images won't be stored in the database, but rather, they'll be stored in a folder that you specify. You can then generate a path for that image, which can and will be stored in the database.